# How to calculate number of database queries in a MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We calculate the no. of db queries in ASP.NET application by searching for ".fill(" or ".execute" and then looking for the query/stored proc.

What is the way we can find the no. of db queries in an MVC application?

This is as part of application analysis...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about your application but I would try to do the following:

- use SQL profiler to see which queries are executed
- create a web crawler to get a list of all links in the application
- click on each link (by hand or from the code) and analyze results from SQL Profiler

Comment: How about searching for "DbContext" in the entire solution. That will take you to the controller. Then, within the Method inheriting from dbcontext you get name of the DbSets. Then you can search for each "DbSetName" which will lead you to the LINQ query!

Comment: As I said, I don't know much about his application. In the application that I'm currently working on, devs were using EntityFramework and PetaPoco. Repository have one method: `public IQueryable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria)` and queries are generated from all over the place :) Before we refactor that, the only way to find out what's going on is to use profilers.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "DbContext" in the entire solution.

This will take you to the controller.

Within the Method inheriting from dbcontext, you get name of all the DbSets.

Then you can search for each "DbSetName" which will lead you to the LINQ query!